# How to send Object data to Api in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api, object

> this is the data i want to send to api

"postcodes": {
"postcode_0": {
"postcode_id": "postcode-0001"
},
"postcode_1": {
"postcode_id": "postcode-0002"
}
},

> this is my code

```
const responsepostal = await axios.post
                (`${urldemo}postal-codes`)
            setData3(responsepostal.data.result)

const [data3, setData3] = useState([])
    const [postcodes, setPostcodess] = useState([]);


 var dataToSend = {
                postcodes: postcodes,
            };

 <Picker style={GlobalSS.picker}
                        // selectedValue={postcodes.toString()}
                        selectedValue={postcodes}
                        mode='dropdown'
                        dropdownIconRippleColor='orange'
                        dropdownIconColor='#FF8025'
                        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
                            setPostcodess(itemValue)
                        }>

                        <Picker.Item color='grey'
                            label="Select Postal Code " value="" />
                        {data3.map(item => (
                            <Picker.Item label={item.text} value={item.id} />
                        ))}
                    </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

for Sending the data in Object

let's create an empty Object

then assign data  to object then send data to API by params

1. let objData = {}
2. objData = postcodes
3. Send this objData to api

Comment: I apply your code then it showed me this error response.JSON ==> {"data": "foreach() argument must be of type array|object, string given", "message": "", "success": false}